# Using Ruby's zip/Hash functionality to build this data structure

Tags: ruby, hash, zip

The surface of what I'm doing sounds trivial. I want to take ActiveRecord objects and build a hash out of them that contains the following format:

Take @records and turn it into:

`{ record.id => [record.attr1, record.attr2], record.id => [...] }`

I am trying to do this using something similar to:

```
Hash[*@records.map{|r| [r.attr1, r.attr2 ]}.flatten]
```

but can't seem to get the correct syntax to make it look like the example above.

** UPDATING TO MAKE MORE CLEAR WHAT IS BEING ASKED **

Let me make a concrete example. I have an array of Cats. This is derived from a Cat model that  has two attributes: name(string) and age(int). I want to retrieve an array of cats by doing the following:

```
# I realize this isn't optimal but that's not the point of this question
@cats = Cat.all.entries
```

I am then attempting to pass a JSON hash to the client where the hash has each cat instance ID as the key and a value which is an array with the cat name and age.

The resulting hash would look something like after the appropriate Hash/zip combo is ran on the @cats array.

```
{ "15" : ["charles", 3], "18" ["winnie", 5], ... }
```

I am attempting to do something like:

```
Hash[*@cats.map{|c| [c.name, c.age ]}.flatten]
```

Does this make more sense?

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: What is `@records`? Do you have an `inspect` result of it?

Comment: I updated the question to include more detail and to further clarify what it is that I'm attempting to ask. I hope this makes more sense? Let me know if I need to add anymore details.

Comment: why you use this `Hash[*@cats.map{|c| [c.name, c.age ]}.flatten]` and using this what wrong you encountered?

Comment: If I understand what do you want this could help: `@cats.each_with_object({}){|el,h| h[el.id] = [el.name, el.age]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def hash_of_arrays(cats)   
  {}.tap do |hashie|   
    cats.each do |cat|  
      hashie[cat.id] = [cat.name, cat.age]  
    end  
  end   
end

puts hash_of_arrays(@cats).inspect
```